# ObjectDisposedException While using Include - why?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-4.1

My page calls a Services layer method that uses a Generic Repository "Find" method. In the services layer method, I do the following:

```
 using (IUnitOfWork unitOfWork = new DBContext())
                {
                    GenericRepository<Operator> operatorRepos = new GenericRepository<Operator>(unitOfWork);
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            var oper = operatorRepos.Find(o => o.OperatorID == operatorID).Include(o => o.cmn_Address).Single();
                            return oper;
                        }
                        catch (InvalidOperationException exc)
                        {
                            //handle exception
                        }
                    }
                }
```

The Find method for my repository:

```
public IQueryable<T> Find(Func<T, bool> predicate)
        {
            return _objectSet.Where<T>(predicate).AsQueryable();
        }
```

On the page, I try to access the cmn_address Navigation property of the Operator and I get the following error:

The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.

I realize that this is caused by the using statement to dispose of the context, but I thought the Include method will eager load the cmn_Address object. I don't understand why this doesn't work as I expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `Func<>` instead of `Expression<Func<>>` in your where condition. That makes it Linq-to-objects. This change is permanent. Calling `AsQueryable` doesn't make it Linq-to-entities again.